# T-SQL - Updating value that isn't changing, is work performed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

This is my first question on here, so please go easy on me :)....I tried searching on the web, as well as other answered questions on here, but I couldn't think of a good way to word this short enough for Google to pick up any good matches. This seems like a T-SQL 101 question to me.

My question is, in T-SQL, when performing an update, if the new value is equal to the current value, is the write still performed (aka, is work done?).

At my job, when we do updates/merges, many times we will use code like the following to do an update (keep in mind, usually the merge/update is for multiple columns, not just the one, like in this example):

`[Column] =
    CASE
        WHEN ISNULL(source.[Column],'') = '' THEN target.[Column]
        ELSE source.[Column]
    END`

Or like this

`[Column]= COALESCE(NULLIF(source.[Column], ''),target.[Column])`

So, in other words, if the source column value is blank, then set it to the target column value...I've always been curious if T-SQL is smart enough to say...hey...they're just trying to set it to itself, screw that.

Also, this could be split into two questions....
Is work performed if the new value is equal to the target value where...

1. the new value is referencing the target value? (meaning, is TSQL smart enough to see it's a reference to itself)
2. the new value is equal to the source value?

I hope this isn't too terribly complex and over thought out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by SQL Server Profiler's tracing of a few experimental `UPDATE` statements, yes, work is performed, but the database engine is pretty smart as expected.

## Experimental `UPDATE` Statements

I traced each of the following `UPDATE` statements in SQL Server Profiler across 4 runs, running them in somewhat different orders to minimize their order of execution as a factor in the trace results:

### `UPDATE` 1

```
update [table]
set CustomerName = CustomerName
where CustomerName = 's/O'; -- value changed from 's/O' to 'o/S' on some runs
```

### `UPDATE` 2

```
update [table]
set CustomerName = 's/O'    -- value changed from 's/O' to 'o/S' on some runs
where CustomerName = 's/O'; -- value changed from 's/O' to 'o/S' on some runs
```

### `UPDATE` 3

```
update [table]
set CustomerName = 'o/S'    -- value changed from 'o/S' to 's/O' on some runs
where CustomerName = 's/O'; -- value changed from 's/O' to 'o/S' on some runs
```

Per my comments next to each `UPDATE`, I flip-flopped between `'s/O'` and `'o/S'` across runs to give each run a value to actually affect in my target table `[table]`.  I could have reset the value in the table after each run, but that is just how I happened to do it.

## SQL Server Profiler Trace Results

Zooming in your browser may make it easier to read the numbers in the following screenshots.  An easier-to-read text summary of average work performed for each `UPDATE` statement follows the screenshots too.

### Run 1 (`UPDATE` 1, `UPDATE` 2, `UPDATE` 3)

[image: SQL Profiler - Updates with Same Values vs. Different Values as Target Values (Run 1)]

This run was a warm-up.  SQL Server was idle on my machine beforehand: so take it with a grain of salt.

### Run 2 (`UPDATE` 3, `UPDATE` 1, `UPDATE` 2)

[image: SQL Profiler - Updates with Same Values vs. Different Values as Target Values (Run 2)]

### Run 3 (`UPDATE` 3, `UPDATE` 2, `UPDATE` 1)

[image: SQL Profiler - Updates with Same Values vs. Different Values as Target Values (Run 3)]

### Run 4 (`UPDATE` 1, `UPDATE` 2, `UPDATE` 3)

[image: SQL Profiler - Updates with Same Values vs. Different Values as Target Values (Run 4)]

### Runs 1-4 Analysis

[image: SQL Profiler - Updates with Same Values vs. Different Values as Target Values (Analysis)]

**Run 2-4 Averages:**

```
Update #    CPU     Reads    Writes    Duration
--------    ---     -----    ------    --------
1           0.00    13.00    1.00      11.33
2           0.00    2.33     1.00      6.67
3           0.00    17.33    1.00      20.00
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the reply! I've never had the opportunity to use profiler before, so pretty cool to be able to go through the data.

BTW, nice bike! :)

Comment: @chadwin: Glad to help. Thanks - noticed your cool moto photo too. :}

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl SET col1 = col1
```

Will still perform the update.